# Need assistance with regards to htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to convert this url:

```
http://something.com/FLSD/DSS/?d=624
```

Into this:

```
http://something.com/FLSD/DSS/624/
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Please don't use l33tsp34k. Please use complete words, as they appear in the dictionary. Also, you need to demonstrate some efforts. Have a look at [Ask].

Comment: @AmalMurali Since they don't accept "help" I went to desperate mod, and used the "3", Sorry.

Comment: Don't be discouraged because your question got downvoted, it's a valid question. People here just prefer you to post code you need help with instead of asking them to do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /FLSD/DSS/\?d=([0-9]+)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /FLSD/DSS/%2\? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^FLSD/DSS/([0-9]+)/?$ /FLSD/DSS/?d=$1 [L]
```

It will convert `http://something.com/FLSD/DSS/?d=624` into `http://something.com/FLSD/DSS/624/`

Comment: one more question. I've tried with letters for another convertion and doesn't work, why? RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /success/\profile?search_user=([A-Z]+)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /success/%2\? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Z]+)?$ /success/profile?search_user=$1 [L] Now i want to convert: http://something.com/success/profile?search_user=user into http://something.com/user code above doesn't work.

Comment: That is because you were looking for upper case letters, change it to `[A-Za-z]`. That will allow it to work for upper and lower case letters.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^FLSD/DSS/([0-9]+)/?$ /FLSD/DSS/?d=$1
```